# How to halt spark streaming until the data recieved in a batch duration is processed?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a situation where I collected data from AWS kinesis to apache spark over streaming. After I receive data for a batch duration, I process those data and update in cassandra. Here the processing should be done in such a way that untill the result is not updated in cassandra, spark should not recive next batch of records.
So, how to halt the streaming of next batch of record until the current batch is not processed?

Answer (score 0):

Spark Streaming does not support this type of functionality. You can simply check row count after you receive data from kinesis for each batch, if there is no record (count equal to zero), don't call cassandra update and insertion API.